# Forward to pages

Tags: jsp, struts2, action

I need some help with referencing static jsp pages from links. ex. `<a href="?"`...

If I called `profile.jsp` from a link it would result 404 and I don't want to call it explicitly ex. http://localhost:8080/profile.jsp, I want to call it from an action. But the action needs a class and I don't want to pass any parameter to the new page I just want to call it as http://localhost:8080/profile .

Best Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe all you mean is to call one jsp from another jsp. If you are using struts2 or any mvc2 based framework request should pass through the controller/action.

struts2 has build in functionality to help you in this case.you need not to create a action class all you have to do is to map this in you struts configuration file.

you have to do something this in your configuration file

```
<action name="profile">
  <result >profile.jsp</result>
</action>
```

If the class attribute in an action mapping is left blank, the `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport` class is used as a default.

The ActionSupport class has an execute method that returns "success" and an input method that returns "input".

read this for details [Action Configuration](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/action-configuration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you register your JSP page as a servlet and map it to an URL in the Deployment Descriptor file ? This can be used when working directly with JSP and servlets:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Error_JSP</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/error.jsp</jsp-file>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Error_JSP</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/error.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```